# Logout from keycloak using the rest api using axios on nodejs doesn't work

Tags: node.js, axios, keycloak

I'm trying to logout from keycloak using the rest api on nodejs

```
    await axios.post(`${process.env.KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout`, {
      client_id: "admin-cli",
      refresh_token: this.refresh_token,
      access_token: this.token,
    })
```

after investigation i discovered that this query does download the html to confirm logout but doesn't logout.
How do i fix it ?

Comment: Can you add some try and catch and some logging of the response ?